# Ranking in Linq

Tags: linq

There's a generic list of numbers, say

{980, 850,700, 680}---n nos.

I try to compare the above list with a decimal no. say 690., the O/p I need is,to get the ranking of the number which I'm gonna input("692). i,e the desired O/P should be Ranking ="4"

How can I get the O/p for above scenario..??

Comment: 680, 690 or 692? What now? Does the input have to match the lists' values?

Comment: Can you explain what role is `690` playing, especially compared to `692`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from Alex's post I think you are looking for

```
var numbers = new List<int>() { 980, 850, 700, 680 };
var dec = new Decimal(692.0);
var temp = numbers.Count(x => x > dec) + 1;
```

this will return the position you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for an exact match of a decimal input to a int on the list,you can use FindIndex.

```
    var numbers = new List<int>() { 980, 850, 700, 680 };
    var dec = new Decimal(680.0);
    var res = numbers.FindIndex(x => x == dec);
```

It returns the 0-based position of the match.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, i'm not sure what role `690` is playing.

Assuming that the user can ernter a number and you want to find the rank(index) of the number in the list when it would be inserted. Assuming also that your list should be sorted descending since you want the position of the new `int` according to it's value:

```
var input = 692;
var numbers = new List<int>() { 980, 850, 700, 680 };
var firstLower = numbers.OrderByDescending(i => i)
    .Select((i, index) => new { Value = i, Index = index })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value < input);
var rank = firstLower == null ? numbers.Count + 1 : firstLower.Index + 1;
```

Note that the `OrderByDescending` might be redundant if your list is already sorted, but i assume that your sample data is only sorted accidentally.